# Vue js image not showing for image path problem

Tags: vue.js

This is a laravel vue project.
 My Image directory "public/images/products".
 My Database image data is "image":"images/products/image_name.jpg". 
My Route path is "127.0.0.1:8000/product". 
In this route path image showing without a problem. 
when my route 127.0.0.1:8000/product/:slug, here my image not showing. Here I inspect element the browser and I see the image path looks like 127.0.0.1:8000/product/:slug/images/products/image_name.jpg. Now How I Fix The Image Link.

My Router.Js

```
{ path: '/product/:slug', component: require('./components/public/singleProduct.vue').default },
```

My Vue File

```
<li v-for="data in product.product_images">
    <img :src="data.image" class="img-fluid"/>
</li>
```

Comment: Now I solve The Problen. The Image Path is <li v-for="data in product.product_images">
    <img :src="'../../'+data.image" class="img-fluid"/>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path, works anywhere (I mean, no matter what current path is).

```
<img :src="'/' + data.image" class="img-fluid"/>
```